# How to use scala type lambda

Tags: scala

With the following code,

```
val x: ({type X[Y] = Function1[Y, Unit]})#X = (y: Int) =>println(y)
```

It successfully compiles, but how could I use it? When I call it with `x(1)`

An compiling occurs that complains `Type mismatch, Y expected: Y accutal: Int`

Comment: @jwvh, It doesn't compile for me either, i change it to val x: ({type X[Y] = Function1[Y, Unit]})#X[Int] = (y: Int) =>println(y). It compiles

Comment: That compiles for you? It doesn't for me. Maybe you mean `#X[Int]`? In that case it compiles, and runs, and prints out its `Int` argument.

Comment: @jwvh...Yes,but I don't know why X should be changed to X[Int], I made the change just from the clue that the compiler  compains.

Comment: You've defined `X` to take a parameter, so it needs a parameter when you reference it.  I'm not sure why you've put together such a complicated arrangement. What you've got can be simplified to just `val x: Int => Unit = (y: Int) => println(y)`

Comment: It can by simplified even further if you want to let the inference engine do its thing: `val x = (y: Int) => println(y)`

Comment: Maybe try changing it to a def[T]

Comment: FYI, you can write it as `Function1[?, Unit]` with https://github.com/non/kind-projector

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments. I am learning Scala Monad, which involves type lambda in some scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a value of a type like `({type X[Y] = Function1[Y, Unit]})#X`, just as you can't have a value of type `Option` or `Function1`. The only thing you can do with it is to apply it to a parameter, or to use it as a type argument for another type/method, which will eventually apply it to some parameters.